# I want a for loop to go through files with two diffrent extensions

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, regex, bash-scripting

I want the following loop to go through m4a files AND webm files. At the moment I use two diffrent loops, the other one just replaces all the m4a from this loop. Also the files that ffmpeg outputs should remove a m4a extension if it was a m4a file, and a webm extension if it was a webm file. And replace that with mp3. (As it does here with m4a). I have no Idea how to do it, I think it has something to do with regex expressions, but I have no idea how really use them nor have I ever found a good tutorial/documentation, so if you have one, please link it aswell.

```
for i in *.m4a ; do
        echo "Converting file $converted / $numfiles : $i"
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel fatal -i "$i" "./mp3/${i/.m4a}.mp3"
        mv "$i" ./done
        converted=$((converted + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

To loop over multiple groups of files in bash, just specify them all in the for list.
If no file matching a group exists (for example no *.webm file), then **for** still loops once (with the group spec (*.webm) as a value of variable **i**). If you want to prevent that you need to [set nullglob option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin):
`shopt -s nullglob`

To strip an extension from a filename (that has an extension!) use this [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):
`${i%.*}`

Your script would then look like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *.m4a *.webm; do
        echo "Converting file $converted / $numfiles : $i"
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel fatal -i "$i" "./mp3/${i%.*}.mp3"
        mv "$i" ./done
        converted=$((converted + 1))
done
```